# Store big integer values correctly in sqlite db

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to store very large int values in sqlite3 db. the values are 100-115 digits long.
I've tried every possible combination - send the input as string/integer and store it as int/text/blob, but the result is always the same - the value of `7239589231682139...97853` becomes  `7.239589231682139e+113` in the db.
My db schema is:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE DATA
    RESULT TEXT NOT NULL''')
```

and the query is:

```
def insert(result):
    conn.execute(f'INSERT INTO DATA (RESULT) VALUES ({result})')
    conn.commit()
```

I wrote a simple function to test the above case:

```
DB_NAME = 'test.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)
conn.execute(('''CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(TYPE_INT INT,
TYPE_REAL REAL,
TYPE_TEXT TEXT,
TYPE_BLOB BLOB);
 '''))
value1 = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
value2 = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
conn.execute(f'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TYPE_INT, TYPE_REAL, TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_BLOB) VALUES ({value1}, {value1}, {value1}, {value1})')
conn.execute(f'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TYPE_INT, TYPE_REAL, TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_BLOB) VALUES ({value2}, {value2}, {value2}, {value2})')
conn.commit()
cursor = conn.execute('SELECT * from TEST_TABLE')
for col in cursor:
    print(f'{col[0]}, {col[1]}, {col[2]}, {col[3]}')
    print('--------------')
conn.close()
```

As you can see - I try all the possibilites, and the output is:

> 1.2345678901234568e+119, 1.2345678901234568e+119, 1.23456789012346e+119, 1.2345678901234568e+119

> 1.2345678901234568e+119, 1.2345678901234568e+119, 1.23456789012346e+119, 1.2345678901234568e+119

Comment: is `result` still a number when you are passing it to `insert` method? if yes have you tried casting it as string first and then pass it?

Comment: @charbel I've tried to pass `result` both as number and string. Either way the value is being passed correctly to `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a value without single quotes so it is considered numeric.
Pass it as a string like this:

```
value1 = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
conn.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TYPE_TEXT) VALUES (?)", (value1,))
```

The `?` placeholder will be replaced by:

```
'123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
```

because the value's type is string and it will be stored properly as `TEXT` which must be the data type of the column.

Comment: Well, it works, but I don't understand your first sentence "You are passing a value without single quotes", since `value1` is a string.

Comment: In a string like `s = f'INSERT INTO DATA (RESULT) VALUES ({result})'` when `result = '123'` the final value of `s` is: `INSERT INTO DATA (RESULT) VALUES (123)` and not `INSERT INTO DATA (RESULT) VALUES ('123')` because `{result}` is replaced by the value of `{result}` without any quotes.

Comment: You could write it like: `f"INSERT INTO DATA (RESULT) VALUES ('{result}')"` to include the single quotes in the string but this is not safe and it is not recommended.